# How do i have my fire simulation have a better framerate/ quality?

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

I'm relatively new to blender, so I do not know entirely how to use it. I followed a fire simulation tutorial to a tea, however my frames would only go to 8 frames per second and the quality of the fire is very poor. How would I go across fixing it?

Comment: The more complex and higher the resolution of your fire is, the more data your computer has to deal with which slows down the playback frame rate. A better hardware might run the animation faster. But all in all this is no real-time game engine, if you want to view it at 'normal' speed like 30 fps or so, you should render the animation as image sequence and playback that. And for the poor quality: how did it look in the tutorial? What is the difference to your simulation? Did you follow the steps there especially regarding the resolution and other special quality-relevant steps?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your GPU, the frame rate in the viewport will reduce when previewing a fire/smoke simulation.  To make the fire look better, you could turn on “noise” and increase the number by the render label but remember to keep the number in power of 2, that usually works for me